# How to invoke a prop directly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am tryng to invoke a props function directly `this.props.setAuth();` , but it doesnt seem to work :/

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

How do you go about invoking a parents function in a child component directly?

I want to change the parents state without any event handlers e.g `onClick={this.props.setAuth}`. I want to do it in a async function so yeah.

Any alternatives would be helpful. Thanks :c

edit: extra code:

```
class LoginPage extends Component {
  constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state = {auth: false}
   this.setAuth = this.setAuth.bind(this)
  }

  setAuth() {
    this.setState({auth: true})
  }
 <App setAuth={this.setAuth}/>
```

below is the `App` component, this is part of the code that I want to call the props function

```
 onSignIn(googleUser) {
```

(useless code) - onSignIn is inside the App component

```
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/auth', {
         userId: id,
         name: name,
         email: email
        })
        .then(function (response) {
        this.props.setAuth();

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });


         }.bind(this));
```

Comment: There are definitely ways to do what you're talking about. Can you post some code so we can take a look at how you've implemented it?

Comment: Add some code to provide more help

Comment: Also, from the error you're getting, it seems like `this` isn't defined in the scope you're trying to call `this.props`. Are you using a function-type child component (i.e. not a class)?

Comment: `.then((response) => { ` and `.catch((error) => {`

Comment: Please post the entire App class component. It would be helpful to go deep into the problem.

Comment: I think @Emersonct is on to it. The this.props.setAuth will have the scope of the 'then' function of the promise.  You might be able to use fat arrows or capture var self = this; outside the axios function.  Its hard to tell exactly with the limited code but bottom line if you put a console.log(this) before the this.props.setAuth I think you will see the scope is not what you think it is.

Comment: In the same scope as the `axios.post` write `const setAuth = this.props.setAuth` and then call it as follows: `.then( function( response ) { setAuth();  }`

Comment: Yes thank you it was because i have a function and it rthis binds to that function, I needed to bind to the component class =D

Answer (score 1):

Here, some example:

My index file has this component and this function:
The component will receive as props a callback function.

```
<ArtistsSearchList 
    onArtistSelect={
        current_artist =>this.setArtist(current_artist)
    }
    key={this.state.term}
    access_token=access_token}
    term={this.state.term} />
```

---

```
setArtist(current_artist){
        this.setState({
            current_artist,
            artist_image_url: current_artist.images[0].url
        });
        var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();
        spotifyApi.setAccessToken(access_token);
        spotifyApi.getArtistAlbums(current_artist.id, {album_type: 'album', limit: 10, market: 'BR'}, (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            // window.location.replace(api_url);
        }
        console.log(access_token);
        console.log("Data: ", data);
        console.log("State current artist: ", this.state.current_artist);
        this.setState({
            albums: data.items,
            selected_album_id: data.items[0].id
        });
    });
}
```

On the ArtistsSearchList component file i have this:
I will pass again as props the method for the component ArtistsSearchListItem

```
 <ArtistsSearchListItem
                key={artist.id}
                current_artist={artist}
                onArtistSelect={this.props.onArtistSelect}
                artist_image_url={artist.images[0].url} />
```

On the ArtistsSearchListItem file, i will finnaly make the call of the methods passed as props through all this way:

```
const ArtistSearchListItem = (props) => {
    const artist_name = props.current_artist.name;
    const artist_image_url = props.artist_image_url;
    return(
        <li onClick={() => props.onArtistSelect(props.current_artist)} className="artist-search-list-item">
            <h3>{artist_name}</h3>
            <img alt="Foto do artista" className="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src={artist_image_url}/>
        </li>
    );
}
```

My repo:
https://github.com/igorPhelype/Spotigorfy

The webapp working:
https://igorphelype.github.io/Spotigorfy/

Comment: This is a wonderful example, thank you for sharing this with me. :)

Comment: thumbs up if you liked it :)